# How do I match on a string read from standard input?

Tags: rust

In an exercise to learn Rust, I'm trying a simple program that will accept your name, then print your name if it's Valid.

**Only "Alice" and "Bob" are valid names.**

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    println!("What's your name?");
    let mut name = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut name)
    .ok()
    .expect("Failed to read line");

    greet(&name);
}

fn greet(name: &str) {
    match name {
        "Alice" => println!("Your name is Alice"),
        "Bob"   => println!("Your name is Bob"),
        _ => println!("Invalid name: {}", name),
    }
}
```

When I `cargo run` this `main.rs` file, I get:

```
What's your name?
Alice
Invalid name: Alice
```

Now, my guess is, because "Alice" is of type `&'static str` and `name` is of type `&str`, maybe it's not matching correctly...

Comment: Try `match name.trim() { ... }`. I can't test it at the moment but I bet there's a newline character in the input.

Comment: that was it...  i always forget about that, thanks!  If you post an answer, i'll upvote and accept.

Comment: If there had been type mismatch it would not have compiled. You can see precisely what’s in a string by formatting it with Debug (`{:?}`) instead of Display (`{}`), too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I bet that it isn't caused by type mismatch. I place my bet on that there are some invisible characters (new line in this case). To achieve your goal you should trim your input string:

```
match name.trim() {
    "Alice" => println!("Your name is Alice"),
    "Bob"   => println!("Your name is Bob"),
    _ => println!("Invalid name: {}", name),
}
```

Comment: A.B. hasn't submitted an answer yet, so i'll just accept yours.